# Rails migration gives error when trying to also create a record in the self.up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have the following migration:

```
def self.up
  add_column :project_statuses, :system_sequence, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false

  ProjectStatus.create :name => 'Declined', :sequence => 35, :system_sequence => 110

  ...
end
```

But when I do a `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
==  NewProjectStatuses: migrating =============================================
-- add_column(:project_statuses, :system_sequence, :integer, {:default=>0, :null=>false})
   -> 0.0029s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

unknown attribute: system_sequence
/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1753:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1747:in `each'
/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1747:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1567:in `initialize'
/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:508:in `new'
/Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:508:in `create'
/[working dir]/db/migrate/20100816100139_new_project_statuses.rb:7:in `up'
```

The erroneous line number refers to the `Project.create :name => ...` line.

It seems like the `add_column` line isn't run at all, even though the output says it is run.

Running a `rake db:migrate` again runs through the migrations fine though.

Why is this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try calling `ProjectStatus.reset_column_information` after the `add_column` block.

Rails caches column information (including which columns exist), and I believe what you're hitting here is that you're creating a column, but that doesn't trigger Rails to reset its cache on the list of available columns. As a result, your following line fails, because it doesn't think the column exists.

I'm not sure why the caching is designed this way, but this sort of thing is [explicitly mentioned in the example code regarding the use](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) of `reset_column_information`. I think there's a pretty good chance that's the issue.

That being said, I also generally agree with [Michael Durrant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631619/michael-durrant), regarding the use of filling the DB with values via migrations. The preferred method is to add your default/seed data to a rake task (which can be run at any arbitrary time), or your `seeds.rb` file. This is in contrast to a migration, which is only run when the current schema version is older than the specified migration.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. Thanks! I may move those offending lines to the seeds.rb file, but I'll need to refactor the migration lines after that first, as it requires those create lines to work.